# Expand less-than sign when using multios and brace expand

Tags: zsh, autocomplete, brace-expansion

With zsh multios set (`setopt multios`) it's possible to do things like:

```
< in1 < in2 > out
```

and:

```
< in > out1 > out2
```

which is very convenient.

I want to combine this feature with brace expand (`setopt braceexpand`), so when I say:

```
<in{1,2}^I
```

(`^I` is a literal tab and invokes the completion system), I want it to expand to:

```
<in1 <in2
```

but instead I get:

```
<in1 in2
```

Is there an easy way to modify this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the completer setting I'm using:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _complete _list _expand _oldlist _ignored _match _correct _approximate _prefix
```

The substitute setting is the default, i.e. 1.

Seeing Chris's answer and pointers in the right direction, made me realize that this must have something to do with my configuration.

I started poking around with the completer order and the substitute setting, none of which changed the behavior. Comparing the settings, using the minimal configuration file provided by Chris, with my own, I narrowed the problem down to my bindkey file, and from there down to `bindkey -v`. This has the side-effect of setting `^I` to `expand-or-complete` which for some reason botches desired expansion.

As I want to continue using the `viins` and `vicmd` keymaps the solution for me was to change tabs behavior to `complete-word`:

```
bindkey -M viins "\CI" complete-word
bindkey -M vicmd "\CI" complete-word
```

**tl;dr**

If you're using `viins` or `viicmd` as keymap remember to change `^I` to `complete-word`:

```
bindkey -M viins "\CI" complete-word
bindkey -M vicmd "\CI" complete-word
```

Answer (score 3):

Your desired behavior worked automatically with my existing completion settings (which were generated by plodding through `compinstall` a few times), so I took some time to narrow down the particular settings that were responsible.

The core functionality is provided by the `_expand` “completer”. You can include it like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand
```

If you are also using the `_completer` completer, then `_expand` needs to be listed first. For example, here is my actual completer setting:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand _complete _ignored _match _approximate _prefix
```

Next, to enable brace expansion, you need to have `substitute` enabled. This is enabled by default, but you can be explicit about it like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' substitute 1
```

If you do not want this enabled everywhere, you can disable it globally and enable it just for `_expand` like this:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' substitute 0
zstyle ':completion:*:expand:*' substitute 1
```

---

I tested this with *zsh* versions 4.3.11 and 5.0.2 by starting a fresh shell with `zsh -df` and sourcing a file containing the following:

```
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _expand
zstyle ':completion:*' substitute 0
zstyle ':completion:*:expand:*' substitute 1
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
```

(The options `multios` and `no_ingore_brace` (which is what `brace_expand` is aliased to) are the defaults, so I did not have to explicitly change them.)

Then, I typed `cat <in{1,2}` and pressed Tab. You will need to press Tab several times: once for each expanded variant and one more time to get to the “all expansions” entry (a total of three times for the above example); I did not find a way to make this particular entry come first.

Comment: Turns out the problem was with my bindkey settings, but thank you for pushing me in the right direction, I'll award the bounty shortly.